# Asymptotic's for Fourier coefficients of $GL(3)$ Maass forms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-program

Let $f$ be a $GL(3)$ Hecke-Maass cusp form and $A(m,n)$ denote its Fourier coefficients.

(1) Are there any lower bounds known for $\sum_{p\leq x}|A(1,p)|^2$ or $\sum_{n\leq x}|A(1,n)|^2$ ? (we know the lower bound $\sum_{m^2n\leq x}|A(m,n)|^2\gg_{\delta} x^{1-\delta}$

(2) Is something known about the dirichlet series (functional equation, meromorphicity etc.)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|A(1,n)|^2}{n^s}$$

I know that the $GL(2)$ analouges for both question is well known.

Comment: answered on MO  https://mathoverflow.net/q/324325/136403